# why the model looks transparent?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using the default diffuse material to show a teapot imported from obj file, but I found the teapot showed in transparent, how to show in opaque mode?

Reference image : [image]

Comment: How many teapots in the scene? Are the others ,reflection or other teapot objects?

Comment: I think problem is, the Normals of object is turn inside. You should check it on 3d applications. If it's true, turn them to outside.

Answer (score 0):

*(Assuming that there's multiple teapots in the scene)*
It looks like the [normals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) of the teapot are facing the wrong way.
Normals are basically vectors holding information about what direction e.g. a face is pointing.

It is very common for shaders to only render the front of any given face to save performance.
This is commonly referred to as "Back-face culling".

**This issue has to be fixed in your 3D editing software.**